# Getting error when using "useEffect" in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use UseEffect react hook but getting error :
React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "cockpit" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import "./cockpit.css";

// it is a css code
const StyledButton = styled.button`
  background-color: ${props => (props.alt ? "red" : "green")};
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 8px;

  &:hover {
    background-color: ${props => (props.alt ? "salmon" : "lightgreen")};
    color: black;
  }
`;

const cockpit = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("in useEffect");
  });

  const classess = [];
  if (props.persons.length <= 2) {
    classess.push("red");
  }
  if (props.persons.length <= 1) {
    classess.push("bold");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
      <p className={classess.join(" ")}>Hi, I am React App</p>
      <StyledButton
        key="B1"
        alt={props.showPerson}
        onClick={props.switchNameHandler}
      >
        Switch Name
      </StyledButton>
      <StyledButton
        alt={props.showPerson}
        key="B2"
        onClick={props.togglePersonHandler}
      >
        Toggle Name
      </StyledButton>
    </div>
  );
};

export default cockpit;
```

Can any one help me to understand why I am getting error .

Dependency in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^4.10.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "radium": "^0.26.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-native": "^0.63.2",
    "react-native-version-update": "^0.2.7",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React, doesn't recognize `cockpit` as a component, because all custom made components [need to be capitalized](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).

To fix that, simply capitalize the name of your component `Cockpit`.

Answer (score 0):

React hooks can only be used at top of functional components or in custom hooks. You can not use a hook inside a function. Check [hook rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).